# How to fix SED inplace replacement Mac OS and Ubuntu Issue

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ubuntu

I have a Bash script which replaces a PHP constant, e.g. `define('xxxx',....);` with desired one.

by:

```
sudo sed -E -i "" "s/^(define).*(${2})[\'|\"].*/${3}/g" "$file"
```

The issue is that on Ubuntu it's failing due to extra space after **i**.

```
-i ""
```

If I remove that space it will work on Ubuntu but will not work on MacOS, e.g. giving an error.

```
sed: 1: "../config.php ...": invalid command code
```

What are the options for me to work this command across the *nix peacefully?

Thank you in advance for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Thank you all for quick response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo perl -pi -e "s/^(define).*(${2})[\'|\"].*/${3}/g" "$file"
```

I suspect you really mean `['\"]`, though.

Comment: let me test this , its seems straight forward

Answer (score 1):

-i option of sed is part of GNU dialect. This is not portable.

One alternative is to use a temporary intermediate file:

```
sed ... ${file} > ${file}.tmp && mv ${file}.tmp ${file}
```

Another one is to use perl instead of sed, [as suggested by triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10811625/45249).

Comment: OS X `sed` supports `-i`, but in a slightly different manner regarding backup extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform the operation in-place and suppress or avoid creation of a backup file, you can set an array conditional on the operating system.

```
[[ $(uname -s) == 'Darwin' ]] && ioption=(-i "") || ioption=(-i)
sed "${ioption[@]}" "s/^(define).*(${2})['\"].*/${3}/g" "$file"
```

An array is used so that quoted arguments and multiple options/arguments all work. You could add more to the array if you wanted to make additional things conditional.

Note that a pipe is not an alternation character inside a bracket expression - instead, it's included literally. So unless you want to potentially match a pipe, you should omit it. Inside the outer double quotes, single quotes don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Williamson, that seems another way. However, tripleee's solutions seems as straight way.

Answer (score 0):

Install GNU sed on OS X and use that.

Comment: Please suggest a solution without extra hassles. Some other command etc which will work across the domain, thanks

Comment: There is no shortage of solutions. Each one is its own hassle.